# 2 words string is not passing through Query String

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I am trying to pass multiple values through query string, and I have done a lot and able to pass the values which are of single word to php page using jquery. But when I am trying to pass the name of User say "Vishal Deb" it is not passing the whole name. I checked in Fire Fox Web console it passing only first half the name means only "Vishal" is passed. 
Here is my jQuery Code

```
$(".searchBtn").click(function(){
    showLoader();

    $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
    $("#content #sub_cont").load("search.php?name=" + $("#name").val() + "&admission_year=" + $("#addyear").val() + "&branch=" + $("#branch").val() + "&course=" + $("#course").val() + "&cclass=" + $("#cclass").val()+ "&fathername=" + $("#fathername").val()+ "&ph1=" + $("#ph1").val()+ "&dura=" + $("#dura").val(), hideLoader());
});
```

And this what I am getting in Fire Fox Web Console after enter my as Vishal Deb

> [15:01:44.149] GET //localhost/daponlinein/admin/search.php?name=%27vishal [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1044ms]

Why this problem is coming can any one guide me.
Thank you

Comment: Try to html encode the parameters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent` to encode values properly before inserting them into a URL context.

Answer (score 1):

A space is an invalid character in a URL query string value. You have to encode it to `%20`.

So your resulting URL should look like:

```
search.php?name=vishal%20deb
```

Don't forget to adjust your PHP code to both serialize and deserialize that properly.

Answer (score 0):

Encode it as:

```
var name = encodeURIComponent($("#name").val());
```